# .ToString Gives an error but Convert.ToString works fine why?

Tags: c#

in my `c#` code i try to write like

```
 public string instancePath = (HttpContext.Current.Application["InstancePath"]).ToString();
```

But when i create the object of this class then it does not works ,it throws an exception. But when i use
 `public string instancePath = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Application["InstancePath"]);` it works perfectly,
Why `convert.ToString()` works `insted of ToString()`? 
any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToString()` needs to exist to call an instance method on it. It does not handle any `null` value. This means that on an object it presumes that the object is not null. However, when we use `Convert.ToString(obj)` it handles null values too. It returns empty if it is null.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
string str = HttpContext.Current.Application["InstancePath"] as string;
```

Comment: I note that while the other answer more directly addresses the specific question (i.e. "why are these two implementations different in behavior?"), this answer seems to more directly address what is likely the best way to actually implement the desired behavior (i.e. because the value probably already is a `string` instance, assuming it's non-null)

Comment: thnaks for your quick replay .